# Call Arduino C/C++ library function from Python

Tags: python, c, arduino, pyserial, arduino-c++

I am trying to do call Arduino C++ library [Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library/blob/master/AFMotor.cpp)
 from the python3.

I have tried with several workarounds. For instance, [Arduino-Python3 Command API](https://pypi.org/project/arduino-python3/#:%7E:text=The%20Arduino%2DPython3%20Command%20API,custom%20protocol%2C%20similar%20to%20Firmata.)
**,**  [pyserial](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) **,** and [pyFirmata](https://pypi.org/project/pyFirmata/) but they have limited support and I want to call [Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library/blob/master/AFMotor.cpp)
 functions from python3.

Also, I've tried with the python subprocess which works but I don't want to use .ino/C++ file.

For instance here is the **python script which uses subprocess call for .ino C++ file.**

```sh
# TODO: Testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import subprocess
    import sys

    # next line must be edited to be appropriate for your PC
    arduinoProg = "/home/arslan/Downloads/arduino-1.8.13/arduino"

    # projectFile = sys.argv[1]
    projectFile = "DCM2.ino"
    codeFile = open(projectFile, 'r')
    startLine = codeFile.readline()[3:].strip()
    actionLine = codeFile.readline()[3:].strip()
    boardLine = codeFile.readline()[3:].strip()
    portLine = codeFile.readline()[3:].strip()
    endLine = codeFile.readline()[3:].strip()
    codeFile.close()

    if startLine != "python-build-start" or endLine != "python-build-end":
        print("Sorry, can't process file")
        sys.exit()

    arduinoCommand = arduinoProg + " --" + actionLine + " --board " + boardLine + " --port " + portLine + " " + projectFile

    print("\n\n -- Arduino Command --")
    print(arduinoCommand)

    print("-- Starting %s --\n" % (actionLine))

    presult = subprocess.call(arduinoCommand, shell=True)

    if presult != 0:
        print("\n Failed - result code = %s --" % (presult))
    else:
        print("\n-- Success --")
```

Lastly, will python `Boost.Python library` can handle this issue? Is there any way to make `shared dll` for [Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library/blob/master/AFMotor.cpp)
 from the python3 and then call from python3 without overwhelming manual changes in src/include of `Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library.`

For instance, I want to convert this simple Arduino code to **Python3**.

```sh
// Arduino code
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
AF_DCMotor Leftmotor1(1);  
AF_DCMotor Rightmotor2(2);  
AF_DCMotor Rightmotor3(3); 
AF_DCMotor Leftmotor4(4); 


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 Leftmotor1.setSpeed(SpeedL1);
  Leftmotor1.run(RELEASE);
  Leftmotor1.run(FORWARD);
  Rightmotor2.setSpeed(SpeedR2);
 }
```

I will appreciate for any comments, and thanks in advnace.

Comment: what are you ultimately trying to achieve? control some motors from your pc?

Comment: I have a python script which is doing object detection using python-OpenCV. The output from the object detection algorithm will control the Motors of differential drive robot. That's why I want to have one python script which does object detection and control motors afterwards.

Comment: whenever I have needed to communicate between python and a device like an Arduino I have used pyserial, you would need to create a set of commands which could be sent over the com port to the Arduino to call the motor shield lib, if you wanted to change these commands or which functions are called, you would need to update the firmware on the Arduino, you might be able to change the firmware and update it all inside a python script, but that seems like it would be complicated to figure out, may lack support for certain features and would be a poor design decision